# Full animation 2D/ How to change colours

Tags: animation, 2d

I am trying to draw on top of the 3D models. When opening 3d model and then selecting " 2D Full Canvas" I can draw well but I can not find how to change colours.

So my question how to change colours in "2D full Canvas mode" ?

Or how to get same template as you get when opening 2D animation from file menu ?[image]

Comment: The screen capture doesn't point at a specific parameter. I don't know what are you trying to accomplish. Please re-formulate your question and point to the parameter you wish to appear vs the screen where it is NOT appearing. Thanks.

Comment: Also, from the screen, it looks like you're ANNOTATING with the ANNOTATION TOOL. You´re really not drawing as in full grease pencil objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the colour under Properties Editor > Material Tab.

In "2D Full Canvas" layout you don't see this editor.

[image]

Since you have some material set, you should switch between materials from 3D View > Properties (N) > Brush just press **Pin** button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In the VIEW TAB, search for ANNOTATIONS. There, open the panel, you can see the colors to switch your drawn strokes:
[image]